# How to close the previous instance before opening another using Fancybox 3?

Tags: jquery, popup, fancybox-3

I have 2 popups: one for the Login window and one for the Sign Up window.
I need to be able to access the Sign up popup from the Login Popup and vice-versa. With fancybox 2, when i open a popup, the others automatically close.

In fancybox 3, they open on top of each other.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no option to do it automatically, but you could run `$.fancybox.getInstance('close');` before opening a new instance.

Comment: Still not working... 

$('.fancybox').fancybox({
    beforeLoad: function() {
      $.fancybox.getInstance('close');
    }
  });